# How to detect and restart program that uses 100% CPU?

Tags: linux

The program `autokey` have a very annoying bug which makes it take up 100% of a CPU core after a few days of running.

If I use `top` and kill the process with `k` then it restarts and is fine for another few days.

```
$ ps ax|grep autokey
 1074 ?        S      0:00 python /etc/rc2.d/S20autokey start
17606 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep autokey
```

**Question**

How do I detect when it is maxing out a CPU core, and then restart from a cron script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually would use a system like [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) or something similar to handle this.

In a case like autokey (do you mean [this](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/)?) I would just use a cronjob that restarts the process every night no matter what if it really always hanging after a few days of run time. This is OK as the program clearly is nonessential. Also, file a meaningful bug report.